# FFmpeg: How to add a fading effect to the video slides?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, slideshow, fading

I have a text file with the names of the images (paths) which I'm using in the video. The file looks like this

```
file 'image1.jpg'
file 'image2.jpg'
file 'image3.jpg'
file 'image4.jpg'
file 'image5.jpg'
```

And the ffmeg command is

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i imagenames.txt -i some_audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -vf fps=30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 output.mp4
```

And I need to add a fading effect to the video slides ( frames ). And I wonder, is it possible to do it using a text file for the images?

Comment: See [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/834035)

Comment: @llogan , seems you saved my day, mate ) Thanks for the great answer

Comment: As for, "is it possible to do it using a text file for the images?" the answer is no.

Comment: @llogan, I'm using this command ```ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i image1.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i image2.jpg -i song.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; [1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; [v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -t 12 -s 1280x720 out.mp4```. The fading effect works but the audio doesn't play in the video. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, I've done it already :)